# PHP Undefined variable inside include

Tags: php

I've got the following function:

```
function get_include_contents($filename, $params = array()) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        extract($params);
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        print_r(get_defined_vars());
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In `$filename` i get passed path to `layout.php` which looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?= $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="todos"></div>
<input id="todo" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="addTodo" value="Add Todo" />
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see I am trying to echo variable `$title` which I get passed into the `get_include_contents` second parameter (`$params`) as an array which I then extract. The problem is I get `undefined variable $title`. By the way the `print_r` inside `get_include_contents` says this:

```
Array
(
[filename] => /home/lchost/EOSS2/app/view/layout.php
[params] => Array
    (
        [title] => Hello World
    )

[title] => Hello World
[contents] => <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="todos"></div>
      <input id="todo" type="text" />
      <input type="button" id="addTodo" value="Add Todo" />
    </body>
  </html>
)
```

which as you can see has defined variable `$title`...
What could be the problem? any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Ok I've fixed this.. the problem was somewhere absolutely else... this was working fine. Admin, you can close this question. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works, the included file starts from the global scope, so it won't see anything defined inside get_include_contents(), your only chance is to use the global environment again:

```
function get_include_contents($filename, $params = array()) {
   global $tpl_params;
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        $tpl_params = $params; // make it global
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        print_r(get_defined_vars());
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

inside your template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?= $tpl_params['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="todos"></div>
<input id="todo" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="addTodo" value="Add Todo" />
</body>
</html>
```

My final advice is to use a dedicated template engine such as Smarty, Twig, Zend_View, or any other. You can find as many as you want, each one has different features and syntax, just pick your favorite one.

Just don't build your own template engine cause you will end up with really serious security bugs.

Comment: I am creating my own Framework without using any of the available templating engines. Check out EOSS2 on github.

Comment: I understand that, I was suggesting you to NOT do it since you clearly don't have a deep PHP knowledge, that's what frameworks are for..